How to fix issue with adding remote conan for cmake project
I am trying to run the install to Stratega for a university project. When running the build command as described in the documentation I keep running into the same issue:
-- Conan: Adding bincrafters remote repository (https://api.bintray.com/conan/bincrafters/public-conan) verify ssl (True)
usage: conan remote [-h] [-v [V]] [-cc CORE_CONF] {add} ...
conan remote: error: unrecognized arguments: True
ERROR: Exiting with code: 2
CMake Error at out/conan.cmake:858 (message):
  Conan remote failed='2'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/settings/Conan.cmake:13 (conan_add_remote)
  CMakeLists.txt:178 (run_conan)

For reference this is the Conan.cmake file:
macro(run_conan)
    # Download automatically
    if (NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
        message(
                STATUS
                "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
        file(DOWNLOAD "https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/raw/0.17.0/conan.cmake"
                "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
    endif ()

    include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)
    
    conan_add_remote(NAME bincrafters URL
            https://api.bintray.com/conan/bincrafters/public-conan)

    conan_cmake_run(
            #Uncomment if building for M1 Apple
            #ARCH armv8
            CONANFILE ${DEPENDENCY_DIR}/${CONANFILE}
            CONAN_COMMAND ${CONAN_PATH}
            ${CONAN_EXTRA_REQUIRES}
            OPTIONS
            ${CONAN_EXTRA_OPTIONS}
            BASIC_SETUP NO_OUTPUT_DIRS
            CMAKE_TARGETS # individual targets to link to
            BUILD missing
    )
endmacro()

I am quite unsure how to proceed or what to do. Any help would be appreciated!
So far I have tried to update the link as per another stack overflow result to
conan remote add bincrafters https://bincrafters.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/conan/public-conan


Your remote error should be relate to https://github.com/bincrafters/community/issues/1456 in case the repository is not available, there is nothing much to do. You can try local-repo-index Conan feature: https://blog.conan.io/2024/04/23/Introducing-local-recipes-index-remote.html
